# PDO "all or nothing" delete transaction

Tags: php, pdo, transactions

I'm new to PDO transactions and have the following scenario: I'd like to delete from two separate tables, with the stipulation that if either delete fails, then neither should occur. This seems like an ideal scenario for transactions. I've tried the following:

```
$db->beginTransaction();

try {
    $db->exec( "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE galleryid = '$gallery_id' AND userid = '1'" );
    $db->exec( "DELETE FROM table2 WHERE galleryid = '$gallery_id'" );
    $db->commit();
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    $db->rollBack();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

In the first delete query, I've queried for something that won't be true (that is, there is no instance in table1 where user_id equals 1). Despite this, the second delete goes through. It could be that this is the expected behavior and I'm not testing this properly.

So, how would I correctly write this using transactions such that **either both deletes go through or neither go through?**

Comment: You're using PDO... why aren't you using parameterized queries?  What you are doing is now likely unsafe.

Comment: you can't use catch, try something like check again errorinfo

Comment: @ajreal, if he sets `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`, then he can use exceptions.

Comment: @Brad, good point. I left that out to keep the example a bit simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a failure or an error if the DELETE matches zero rows.

If you want to test how many rows a DELETE affected, use [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

Here's an example:

```
$db->beginTransaction();
try {
    $del1 = $db->prepare( "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE galleryid = :galleryid AND userid = :userid" );
    $del1->execute(array(":galleryid"=>$gallery_id, ":userid"=>1));
    if ($del1->rowCount() < 1) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Delete from table1 matched no rows.")
    }

    $del2 = $db->prepare( "DELETE FROM table2 WHERE galleryid = :galleryid" );
    $del2->execute(array(":galleryid"=>$gallery_id));
    if ($del2->rowCount() < 1) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Delete from table2 matched no rows.")
    }

    $db->commit();
} catch( RuntimeException $e ) {
    $db->rollBack();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

---

Re your comment:

This is a fine application of transactions.  That is, you want deletions from table1 and table2 to be applied at the same time, and don't let data be deleted from one table and not the other.

It sounds like you want to abort both deletes if either of them match no rows.  I've expanded my code example above to show a more complete example.  If the example hadn't used transactions to group the two changes, it could allow the first delete to succeed and then find that the second delete doesn't delete anything.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Would my case therefore not be a sensible use of PDO transactions? I was unable to find any examples of transactions and DELETE when I searched on Google and SO.

Answer (score 3):

Just because your first query affects 0 rows doesn't mean it would throw an exception, so there's nothing to catch. I'm not really sure if that's what you're after but you might want to use `PDOStatement::rowCount()` to check the number of rows affected by your `DELETE`.